# Is there a function like `assoc` that returns all matching values?

Tags: association-lists

The `assoc KEY LIST` function returns the first element of an `alist` whose car is equal to `KEY`.

Is there a built-in Emacs Lisp function which returns *all* elements of the `alist` whose cars are equal to `KEY`, as a sub-alist, or list of values? After all, there is no requirement that an `alist` have unique keys.

That is,

```
(assoc foo '((foo . 5) (bar . 6) (foo . 7))) = '(foo . 5)
```

But,

```
(assoc-all foo '((foo . 5) (bar . 6) (foo . 7))) = '((foo . 5) (foo . 7))
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```el
(require 'cl-lib)

(cl-remove-if-not (apply-partially #'equal 'foo)
                  '((foo . 5) (bar . 6) (foo . 7))
                  :key #'car)

=> ((foo . 5) (foo . 7))
```

```el
(defun assoc-all (key list &optional testfn)
  "Like `assoc', but returns the list of all matching elements."
  (cl-remove-if-not (apply-partially (or testfn #'equal) key)
                    list :key #'car))
```

Comment: Please prefix function names with `#'` instead of just `'` to tell the compiler this is a function reference (works for both `'equal` and `'car`)..

Comment: Done; although to my knowledge this is entirely redundant in this instance -- it would only affect anything if `car` or `equal` might not be defined, no?

Comment: According to your definition, `#'` is always redundant as you are supposed to only reference defined functions :-). I think it's a good habit to always sharp-quote your function references. And, who knows, the byte compiler might one day use this information to optimize your code :-).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution involving `seq-filter`:

```
(seq-filter (lambda (elt) (equal (car elt) 'foo))
            '((foo . 5) (bar . 6) (foo . 7)))
```